# Ionic googleplus plugin: Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: ionic-framework, authentication, x-frame-options

I am facing this issue when running in browser mode. How can I solve this? Would be possible to open this dialog in a new tab instead of an iFrame?

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

Many thanks for the help!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Using Ionic with following settings:

```
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.3.2 "Google SignIn"


Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.5 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0, browser 5.0.4, ios 4.5.5

System:

   NodeJS : v8.11.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 5.6.0
   OS     : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode  : Xcode 10.0 Build version 10A255
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser plugin.

[Coexist with inAppBrowser plugin (fixed)](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/pull/577)

Comment: thanks! it worked after uninstalling inappbrowser plugin. Error is gone!

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins can only be tested/working inside a device.

I remember that the google+ sign need to use the google play services and the apk signature those things aren't available running in local browser with chrome.

It's likely you test the android push notifications with the chrome it won't work.

For these type of things better if you call the ionic with the live reload to test in the device and reload when you make changes

```
     ionic cordova run android -l -c
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for replying. But it is supposed to be able to work in browser mode according to https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus#browser , actually, i've already have it working for mobile devices. The problem in the browser seems to be opening an iframe instead of new tab.